# Joomla not loading all page

Tags: joomla

Hi I have a problem I dont know why but visiting site with chrome (ffox seem to work fine[also some times not perfect]) it doesnt load all or any pictures (pictures use capty)
Example: http://www.artzone.lv/joomla/arhitektura/musu-projekti/2013-gads
But when year example 2013 is pressed twice it load fast and everything works just fine
So what can i do to fix this ? This is emergency client is waiting to site to be finished..
Than you!

Comment: check error console in firefox, you'll see you have some font issue, maybe it prevents loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are loading fine. Your problem is javascript.

Your `.capty-wrapper` divs are being resized with javascript to reach the same high as the image. But your javascript isn't waiting for the images. If you reload the page, the images are in your cache, which is why your browser can render them fast enough.

So you can do the following things:

1) Optimize your javascript to wait for the images.

2) Optimize your javascript to not change the height (i see no reason why you need that).

3) Set width and height attributes to the image, so the browser knows the size even before the image is loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped. I'd give you a cookie if I had one :D

Comment: I'm glad. If the answer were helpfull you could accept it and/or vote it up instead of the cookie ;)

Comment: Yeah sure ;) However i cant up it (Vote Up requires 15 reputation)